# Proper placing figures, tables and text

Tags: tables, floats, formatting

I have the following page:
[image: here]

I can't correctly set the spacing between the table (red pencil on screen), pictures and text.
The layout of this page is: table - little of text - new section - little of text - figure (next page)

Instead, I want to start at the top, use appropriate spacing, and leave free space after the last paragraph of the text.
I use:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
...
\end{figure}
```

for positioning because I want the logical context of the document.
How can I perform this?

Comment: The best option is not to use floats (`figure` or `table`) if you do not want things to float. Then you have to manage vertical space yourself. Given that you did not provide a compilable example, we do not know which class, options, or packages you are using, so: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes. Maybe `\raggedbottom` can help?

Comment: OK, it works, thank you. I was looking for a floats setting but finally succeeded``` \raggedbottom ```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat would be a helpful reading!